# App bookmark not visible on the left-side "Apps" section

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, bookmarks

My Open Graph enabled app does not generate app bookmark on the left side of Facebook homepage (near the "Apps" section).

The application in question is located here:

http://apps.facebook.com/lrytaslt/

It's in Lithuanian, but clicking on any news link will ask you for basic permissions and once approved will redirect to the inner news page. By this time it should be added to the left side as a bookmark. It does not happen. I can't even see the app under the "MORE" link, however the app is visible under the "Apps and Games" link as an icon (with no way to "favorite" it to get it as a regular bookmark link).

Is this intended behavior? A new Facebook feature or a bug? Has anyone run into any similar bookmark-related issues?

**Edit:** Attached a small screenshot with the issue:

[image: App bookmark issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That app automatically redirects elsewhere when I open it, that's probably why there's no bookmark -

Bookmarks are only available for Canvas apps according to the documentation - you shouldn't redirect if you want a bookmark

The bookmark is added automatically after the user continually uses your canvas app for a few minutes

Comment: Yes, my app is implemented as a page tab, however it will redirect to the canvas page after the auth dialog to "mark" it as a canvas app. It does have accessible canvas page and URL (redirecting back to the page tab). This is not my first app implemented this way, but the first one to actually have issues with bookmark not being visible. I feel there is something more to this than the app not being a regular canvas one.

Comment: Unless the app is actually used on canvas and isn't just a redirect the bookmark isn't created - the bookmark is created automatically when the user uses the app on canvas for a period of time ( im unsure how long exactly but it's somewhere from 2-5 minutes i think)

Comment: Alright, if it's timed to several minutes then that could be the case. I will offer to my client to redo the app as a pure canvas one and will let you know if that did the trick.

Comment: Note that if it's a redirect app, you also won't get the 'is playing' or 'is using' stories in ticker which are necessary for App Used sponsored stories, which may also be something your client wants

Comment: Thanks again, having the application as a canvas one solved my missing bookmark problem.